# Existence of a similar nilpotent matrix in a general sense.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let there be a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $n$ with $L : V \rightarrow V$ a nilpotent operator with index $k$. If $L$ is diagonalizable then I know that it is similar to the $0$ matrix. I was curious in an extension of this, that is does there exists a finite dimensional (say m) $\mathbb{C}$ vector space $W$ and  $L' : W \rightarrow W$ another nilpotent operator such that $$L \oplus L'\;is\;similar\;to\;0 \oplus L'. $$
Now if $L$ was diagonalizable then $L \oplus L'$ is similar to $0 \oplus L'$ for any $L'$. Because I can take the invertible matrix as the block diagonal matrix
$\begin{pmatrix}
[P_1] & [0] \\
[0] & [I_m]
\end{pmatrix}$ where $P_1 L P_1^{-1} = [0]$. So what I am trying to find is does there exists a pair ($W,L'$) of an $m$ dimensional vector space $W$ and a nilpotent endomorphism $L'$, and an $(n+m \times n+m)$ matrix $Q$ such that $$Q 
\begin{pmatrix}
[L] & [0] \\
[0] & [L']
\end{pmatrix} Q^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
[0] & [0] \\
[0] & [L']
\end{pmatrix} $$ given a pair $(V,L)$ of an $n$ dimensional vector space and a nilpotent endomorphism $L$. I was trying with the pair $(\mathbb{C}^2,\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} )$ but having no luck. So if anyone could help me I will be highly obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false for every nonzero nilpotent operator $L$ (on a finite-dimensional vector space). Rank is additive with respect to direct sum and invariant under similarity, so $\text{rank}(L \oplus L') = \text{rank}(L) + \text{rank}(L')$ has strictly larger rank than $\text{rank}(0 \oplus L') = \text{rank}(L')$ and so the two can't be similar.

(Also, you don't need to say "similar to the zero matrix": the zero matrix is the unique matrix similar to itself so a matrix similar to the zero matrix is just identical to the zero matrix.)

Comment: Oh, right I forgot to check the basics, my bad. Thank you.